# LIBGDX Perspective Camera in an Isometric view?

Tags: java, libgdx, mathematics

how can I set a `PerspectiveCamera` to view the game in an isometric view? What kind of angle would I use, and how would I actually translate this into the code? Math isn't my forte, so I can't really understand the maths on the wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection). It mentions to points A and B, but I'm not sure what those points would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. A `PerspectiveCamera` uses a projection that gives you perspective, but for an isometric projection you don't want any perspective.

You can use the `OrthographicCamera` and tilt it in an angle that works for you, the projection does not use perspective.

Comment: Oh I see. Do you know why my rendered objects are tiny with an orthographic camera? My objects were mostly cubes that were 15x15x15, is that too small?

Comment: @floyan You can position your camera to get your cubes to be as big or as small as you like, regardless of their size. I am guessing your field of view might be off.

Comment: Ooh okay, thanks for your help. Last little mini question I promise! What axis would the player move on, and when I set the camera to `camera.lookAt(Vec3)` what player position axis does it need to follow? Thanks!

Comment: @floyan Impossible to answer without knowing more about your game. Which axis the player should move on is up to you. If you're still unsure, post a new question.